# Why data is repeating in ssas dimension

Tags: ssas

I have an SSAS cube with time as one of the dimention.It contains hierarchy like year-quarter-month etc.When i drag and drop the this on SQL Server Managment Studio window(brows), it looks like data is repeating.For example,year is like 2002,2002,2003,2003,.. etc.If i expand first 2002 i can see 1st quarter under that.If i expand second 2002 i can see 2nd quarter etc..Can any one tell what is the reason? how can i change to single data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all are you using your own Date Dimension table. If so, make sure you use the correct key for Date, Month, Quarter and Year. For example, normally the date dimension has YearMonth column used as the key for the Month attribute (eg 2012-04). If you don't have such a column you will need to pick a composite key for Month (Year and Month). Also, a good way to check is in the dimension designer in BIDS go the browser tab of the dimension and make sure the hierarchies are showing up fine.

Comment: Hi,key column is year-month only.I have checked from browser tab.still it is showing repeated values.

Comment: Hi, I got it.. Actually i have created composite key for year also(month-year).when i removed month from that it works.